# What is This Issue Called & How To Solve it

Tags: modeling

I have downloaded this File from the Internet and it was in OBJ format, When I imported it in Blender, this is how it is showing completely broken, and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me out!!

Blender Version: 2.93

[image: Broken Mesh]

Comment: Difficult to say with only a screenshot, probably precision errors? they happen if the model its very big, check the scales of the model, it's a character it should not pass the 2 meters in height

you can check that in 3D Viewport> **N** > Item > Dimensions

Comment: It's alpha sorting issues. Turn off backface culling or switch the blend mode in the material properties. Or switch to Cycles.

Comment: maybe try Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?